# Vue.use(BootstrapVue) don´t works

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use the bootstrap library in my Vue project, after having installed it as indicated in the bootstrap official page I do the imports in the main.js file and when I use Vue.use(BootstrapVue) my application stops working because Vue is undefined.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue) //here is the problem

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Comment: You're using Vue 3, which BootstrapVue does not support.

Comment: yes I have realised this is the problem, thanks!!